# How to apply paging on CheckboxList Control

Tags: asp.net

How to apply Paging on CheckboxList Control, and also how to maintained checkboxes checked status.

Comment: not sure paging is supported at all in WebForms CheckboxList Control. I would use a Grid with a template item and put the checkbox in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use the CheckBoxList control, it appears you'll have to implement a PagedDataSource as well.

Here's an article that talks about just that:

[Paging using a CheckBoxList, a PagedDataSource and the Ajax.NET](http://icomparable.blogspot.com/2008/09/paging-using-checkboxlist.html)

[PagedDataSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx)